# ASP.NET MVC Pass the ID in URL to SSRS parameter to execute the report

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am trying to do a SSRS report for a .NET application.
I have everything running in the SSRS part but my query has a parameter because the report has a different id for each report.

Imagine I click on a user that I want a report about, that user has the id = 2 the parameter in my SSRS gets the id then executes the query depending on the id.

How can I export the id to the SSRS query from the web page ?

Comment: How are you invoking the SSRS report from .NET? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this in the past using SSRS 2012.

When using the SSRS server's web report viewer (`ReportViewer.aspx` page) to display the report to the user in their browser, you can pass values for report's parameters by including them in the query string part of the URL in the format `ParameterName=value`.

For example, to pass the value 2 to a parmeter called UserID, append `&UserID=2` to the report URL.

The parameter name is case sensitive if I remember correctly.

As an extra, if you just want to render the report and don't need the user to see or be able to change the parameters on the report viewer page then you can also add `&rc:Parameters=false` to the URL.

An example URL would then look something like:
`http://MySSRSServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportPath&UserID=2&rc:Parameters=false`